# ApolloServer.applyMiddleware({ express }) getting UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'use of undefined

Tags: express, apollo-client, next.js, apollo-server, express-graphql

```js
const { ApolloServer, gql } = require('apollo-server-express')

const express = require("express");
const next = require("next");

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV === "development";
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();
app.prepare().then(() => {
  
  const apoloSrv = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs, resolvers });
  const server = express();
  apoloSrv.applyMiddleware({ server});
  
  server.get("*", (req, res) => handle(req, res));

  const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;
  server.listen(PORT, err => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(`Ready on :${PORT}`);
  });
});
```

Following are the code snippet for the apollo-server-express connect with the express framework using nextjs

Here I want to configure the graphql using apollo-server-express 2.0 .
When I am using this code using node server.js then I am getting the following error message like ,

"(node:2904) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'use' of undefined"

could someone take a look into it and let me know what are the issues here.

Answer (score 13):

The example in the docs is:

```
const app = express();
server.applyMiddleware({ app });
```

This means you are passing an object to the `applyMiddleware`. In the example, the object we pass in is initialized using [shorthand property name notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015), which was introduced with ES2015. The above is equivalent to:

```
server.applyMiddleware({ app: app });
```

Our object has a property named app, the value of which equals a variable that happens to also be called app. If you did this:

```
const myApp = express()
server.applyMiddleware({ myApp });
```

That would mean you were passing in an object with a `myApp` property, and more importantly, missing the `app` property the `applyMiddleware` function expects. So... your code needs to look like this:

```
apoloSrv.applyMiddleware({ app: server});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const { ApolloServer, gql } = require('apollo-server-express');

const server = new ApolloServer({
    schema: schema,
    introspection: true
}); 

server.applyMiddleware({ app:router });

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: While this might answer the question, your should [edit] your answer to provide an explanation of *how* this answers the question, which helps provide context for future readers. A code block by itself is not immediately useful for those who might come across the same issue later on.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using:
`server.applyMiddleware(app)`

use this:
`server.applyMiddleware({ app })`